# Unity line renderer smooth algorithm

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, line, smoothing

I need an !effective! algorithm to smooth a line renderer (basically, the given Vector3 which holds the points of the renderer)

something like that
[image] 
Here is my code, but the fps with it is very low:

```
public static List<Vector3> MakeSmoothCurve(Vector3[] arrayToCurve, float smoothness)
{
    List<Vector3> points;
    List<Vector3> curvedPoints;
    int pointsLength = 0;
    int curvedLength = 0;

    if (smoothness < 1.0f) smoothness = 1.0f;

    pointsLength = arrayToCurve.Length;

    curvedLength = (pointsLength * Mathf.RoundToInt(smoothness)) - 1;
    curvedPoints = new List<Vector3>(curvedLength);

    float t = 0.0f;
    for (int pointInTimeOnCurve = 0; pointInTimeOnCurve < curvedLength + 1; pointInTimeOnCurve++)
    {
        t = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, curvedLength, pointInTimeOnCurve);

        points = new List<Vector3>(arrayToCurve);

        for (int j = pointsLength - 1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                points[i] = (1 - t) * points[i] + t * points[i + 1];
            }
        }

        curvedPoints.Add(points[0]);
    }

    return (curvedPoints);
}
```

Comment: Do you have Bezier curve primitives in your framework/library?

Comment: No, not yet. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I don't know unity and cannot understand - whether it contains in-build Bezier? http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/bezier-curve-in-games shows manual drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CurveField

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.CurveField.html

With that you can easily edit/test your curve and retrieve a point at given time.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html